# How to use "Result Variable Name" in JDBC Request object of Jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

In JMeter I added the configuration for oracle server. Then I added a JDBC request object and put the ResultSet variable name to `status`.
The test executes fine and result is displayed in treeview listener.

I want to use the variable `status` and compare it with string but jmeter is throwing error about casting arraylist to string.

How to retrieve this variable and compare with string in While Controller?

Comment: I used the resultset variable like ${status.get(0).get("STATUS")} == "READY" in the while condition and it didnot throws error but then the thread keeps running when it should have stopped executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ResultSet variable returned with JDBC request in JMeter are in the for of array. So if you want to use variable `status`, you will have to use it with index. If you want to use the first(or only) record user `status_1`. So you need to use it like `status_{index}`.

Comment: I don't understand either.  Are you saying to access the variable from Beanshell like:  ${status_1} ??  I tried that and it didn't work.  Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: check out the documentation: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request . there is an example at the beginning on how the "underscore-syntax" works. it helped me figuring it out. it's like: every field in the resultset gets a variable and you select the row by using the_-syntax.

Comment: Hey, people, you are all talking about wrong topic: The question title mentions clearly "How to use “Result Variable Name” ". And there is only one "resultset", see the "Result variable name". What you describe is the excel-like addressing into the resultset table, to get particular values. :-/

Answer (score 6):

Just used some time to figure this out and think the accepted answer is slightly incorrect as the JDBC request sampler has two types of result variables.

The ones you specify in the `Variable names` box map to individual columns returned by your query and these you can access by saying `columnVariable_{index}`.

The one you specify in the `Result variable name` contains the entire result set and in practice this is a list of maps to values. The above syntax will obviously not work in this case.

Comment: The accepted answer talks about the excel-like mechanism jMeter offers for addressing into the resultset table, to get particular values. So off topic, another offtopic mechanism than usage of "the asked just-the-single resultset object", and the "dots" access to its child objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
 String host = vars.getObject("status").get(0).get("option_value");
 print(host);
 log.info("----- " + host);
```

Form complete infromation read the "yellow box" in this link: 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request

Other util example:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beanshell/Groovy (same code works) in `JSR233 PostProcessor` to work with “Result Variable Name” from JDBC Request like this:

```
ArrayList results = vars.getObject("status");

for (HashMap row: results){
    Iterator it = row.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        log.info(pair.getKey() + "=" + pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

Instead of output to log replace with adding to string with delimiters of your choice.